# Eloquent - How to match data between tables of a single ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.8

Having multiple tables with data that relates to each other, i'm trying to display that data in a view using Laravel.

I must be confused with how Laravel runs its queries and I need help to sort how to do, what in PHP&SQL would be a left join.

My Asset Model:

```
public function category(){
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
    }
```

My Category Model:

```
public function asset()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class);
    }
```

My Country Model:

```
public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class);
    }
```

And my AssetsController:

```
public function asset($id)
    {

        $asset = Asset::find($id);

        return view('admin.assets.asset')->with('assets', $asset);

    }
```

And the Router:

```
Route::get('/admin/assets/asset/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'AssetsController@asset',
        'as' => 'assets.asset'
        //Show the Asset
    ]);
```

And the View:

```
<p><strong>Price:</strong>{{$assets->price}} €</p>
<p><strong>Description:</strong>{{$assets->description}}</p>
<p><strong>Country:</strong>{{$assets->country}}</p>
<p><strong>Category:</strong>{{$assets->name}}</p>
```

So in the 'asset.blade.php' I get the id from a previous index.blade.php that has a list of all the assets. I want to get via the ID, an asset page that displays the category name and the country name, instead of the ID that belongs to the Asset table.

So it should echo something like `$assets->country->country_name` and `$assets->category->name`

[dd($asset);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs0xz.png)

EDIT: Additional information about migrations

categories_table migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

assets_table migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('assets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('price',15,2);
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->integer('country');
            $table->integer('category');
            $table->integer('subcategory');
            $table->integer('subsubcategory');
            $table->integer('broker');
            $table->string('featured');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

```
class Category
{
    public function asset()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Asset
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

```
use App\Asset;
use App\Category;
use App\Country;
use App\Subcategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssetController extends Controller
{
    public function asset($id)
    {
        $asset = Asset::find($id);

        return view('admin.assets.asset')
            ->with('asset', $asset)
            ->with('category', Category::all())
            ->with('subcategory', Subcategory::all())
            ->with('country', Country::all());
    }
}
```

The other models have the same relationship towards the `Asset` model and vice-versa.

The View:

```
<p><strong>Category:</strong>{{$asset->category->name}}</p>
<p><strong>Sub-Category:</strong>{{$asset->subcategory->name}}</p>
```

It now shows the name matching the id of the corresponding tables.

Comment: I wonder why you return `Category::all()`, `Subcategory::all()` and `Country::all()` to your view as well. Do you need it for the options of a select box or something similar? To improve your code slightly and make the loading of relationships more explicit, use `Asset::with(['category', 'subcategory'])->find($id);` instead. Otherwise Laravel will simply load these relationships on first access, which is quite magic. It doesn't matter with `find($id)` (single model), but with `get()` (multiple models) it makes a performance difference.